# Python: Serverless Authentication working, but lambda not getting invoked

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, serverless

I have an running with serverless framework and python. I implemented a authentication function and registered it in the serverless.yaml. For testing, I just configured for one lambda function to be called after the authentication function. The authentication function gets called without any error, but the lambda function resolves in a 500 Internal Server Error

I tried the serverless docs, but a lot of examples regarding my issue are not written in python, so its not helping me

expected result: no error when calling lambda function
output: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: You have not provided any code to help people help you.  Please add details that will allow people to look into your problem.

Comment: Sounds like a runtime error in your Lambda function so you need to learn how to debug your Lambda function. One way is to have it print debug statements to stdout and that will be captured in CloudWatch Logs.

Comment: Your lambda function seems to be broken, some code might help us understand better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not providing any code, but I actually found the solution. I did not generate any policy for the api gateway :D